# Having a TLS issue with Kestrel and Cortana with Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: ssl, asp.net-core, botframework, cortana, direct-line-botframework

I've created a direct line bot for the Microsoft Bot Framework using .net core. I'm attempting to integrate it with Cortana but when I try to launch the app with Cortana I'm seeing this error:

```
A call to SSPI failed, The client and server cannot communication, 
because they do not posses a common algorithm.
```

This certificate was working when I was using the Microsoft Bot Framework nuget package with .Net 4.6 so I'm fairly confident it doesn't have anything to do with the cert (which is signed by Let's Encrypt)

This is my setup:

```
 var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                //options.UseHttps("cert.pfx", "********");
                options.UseHttps(new HttpsConnectionFilterOptions()
                {
                    SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12,
                    ServerCertificate = new X509Certificate2("cert.pfx", "******")
                });
            })
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .UseUrls("https://*:8090")
            .Build();

        host.Run();
```

I originally didn't have the SSLProtocols defined and had this issue, adding the protocol to support Tls12 didn't help (I'm assuming that was probably the default anyway).

Any insight is greatly appreciate.

Comment: Unfortunately, Bot Framework doesn't support .NET core just yet. To track this issue, see: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/572

Comment: Would this really stop SSL from working correctly though? I moved my controllers and logic over exactly as I had it in .net core to 4.6, bound the cert using netsh and everything is working exactly as expected. I also find it interesting that the chat window test and other direct line connections work fine, it's only the call from Cortana that are failing. The point of the Direct Line integration is that it'll work in any language so I don't think this is a compatibility issue with the bot framework itself.